# c++ reference to overloaded function could not be resolved;

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        const int size = 15;
        char array1[size];
        char array2[size] = "four";
        cout << array2[3]='\0' << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Hello, I am new to C++, I am learning the C-string, my question is why
`array2[3] ='\0'` can not be use inside the `cout`, the error I get is:

```
 reference to overloaded function could not be resolved.
```

It works fine if it's outside of `cout`. thank you :)

Comment: Shift operator has higher precedence than assignment. That line is interpreted as `(cout << array2[3]) = ('\0' << endl);` which is nonsense. If you really want to combine assignment and output for some reason, enclose the assignment in parentheses.

Comment: ... But don't combine output and assignment. Clever code is often opaque code, and you or someone else will damage it later during maintenance.

Comment: thank you, another question, if i only put down int size =15, without using keyword const, why there will be error on array2?

Comment: that's a separate question. one question per posting--this keeps it easy for future people to find relevant questions.

Comment: It appears you could use a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Because C++ requires array size to be fixed at compile-time (i.e. be a compile-time constant). `const int size = 15;` counts as a compile-time constant, and `int size = 15;` is not even a constant.